# Change all values for an individual from "yes" to "no"

Tags: excel, vba, replace, find

I created my first userforms to capture hospital data but now I'm stuck.

I want to change all values for "Current inpatient" in column "B:B" from "yes" to "no" for a given patient when I click "Remove from ITU".

Example data
[image]

Userform to change patient from "Yes" to "no" in the "current inpatient" column
[image]

Comment: Apparently you have a table of patients, where Patient CC is the unique key. This table should contain the field for Current inpatient, which you can change on that single line with the form. The Current inpatient field in the shown table should be a vlookup formula into the patients table.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try the next code, please:

```
Sub ChangeYesToNo()
  Dim sh As Worksheet, curInp As String, lastRow As Long, i As Long
  Set sh = ActiveSheet
  lastRow = sh.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
  curInp =  Me.ComboBox1.Value  'use here your combo name

  For i = 2 To lastRow
    If CStr(sh.Range("E" & i).Value) = CStr(curInp) Then
        If sh.Range("B" & i).Value = "Yes" Then
            sh.Range("B" & i).Value = "No"
        Else
            MsgBox "Strange situation in row """ & i & """."
        End If
    End If
  Next i
End Sub
```

Not tested, written on a tablet without Excel installed, but it should work...

Comment: Worked a treat! Thanks so much!

Comment: @Jamie: Glad I could help! But we here, when a solution answers the question, tick the left code side check box in order to make it **accepted answer**. In this way, somebody else searching for a similar issue will know that the answer code worked...

Comment: May I know who voted the code down? And especially, **why**?  It is, at least, polite to say what is wrong with my code, especially when the person asking the question considers it appropriate...